# Footer overflow on Ask Question page

Tags: bug, design, meta, footer

If you scroll down on the Ask Question page you get a 'footer overflow' as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Ok, it's a dupe. But this title is better!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same problem, so meh.

Comment: Ah, now that does look like a proper dupe indeed, my bad that I didn't find that one.